# Error in Android Studio after impoit the library from github

Tags: android, github

it is error

```
Error:Illegal char <:> at index 76: C:\Users\sahar\AndroidStudioProjects
\android-job\library\build\outputs\aar\C:\Users\sahar\AndroidStudioProjects
\android-job\library\build\outputs\aar\android-job-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT.aar
```

Comment: Please describe exactly what you did. This looks like there are two file names concatenated.

Comment: Why is it repeating the address? `\build\outputs\aar\C:\Users\sahar\`

Comment: What is this? please explain your problem.

Comment: I got a library from github
And Android Studio makes this error

Comment: delete build folder of app, rebuild and run it again.

Comment: How to rebuild؟

Comment: Sorry i am very beginner

Comment: Salam.
I also get this error while try open source code of demo application of `https://github.com/evernote/android-job` inside Android Studio.
The path specified in error not exists! and I don't know why this error happened and how to resolve it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has the same problem with source code of [`evernote android-job`](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) in version `1.2.4`, when I try to open source code inside Android Studio `3.0.1`.

After some test and tries solve the problem by comment this line:

`//apply from: '../build-config/gradle-push.gradle'`

of file `android-job-1.2.4\library\build.gradle` that's last line.